# DDMathParser failing to tokenize solitary plus character

Tags: objective-c, ddmathparser

Using `DDMathStringTokenizer`, while something like `2 + 4` tokenizes fine into 3 tokens (with the second being the + operator and the first and third being numbers), if I pass over a `+` alone, it **fails to return it as a token**.

This does not hold true for every other operator I've tried, such as `/` `*` `-` etc.

I can probably force this somehow but how can I get `DDMathStringTokenizer` to tokenize the `+` correctly?

To reproduce the issue:
The following will return an array with no objects. If you change the `string` value to another operator character it will return a valid array.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = @"+";
DDMathOperatorSet *opSet = [DDMathOperatorSet defaultOperatorSet];
DDMathStringTokenizer *tokenizer = [[DDMathStringTokenizer alloc] initWithString:string operatorSet:opSet error:&error];
NSLog(@"Tokens:%@", [tokenizer allObjects]);
```

Comment: I suspect that since it doesn't know if it's an add or a positive it might just return nil? But then that should also happen with `-`.

Comment: Probably better to write this to the DDMathParser issue tracker: https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/issues

Answer (score 0):

This is the tokenizer trying to be too smart. Since the `+` character is the first token, it's assumed to be a unary operator (no left-hand-side). It then gets dropped on the floor, because unary `+` is a worthless operator: it doesn't affect evaluation, so it gets omitted from the token stream.

I believe this is better on the 1.1 branch, but I haven't had time to finish integrating changes in to master.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Is the 1.1 worth moving to or better to wait until you merge?